# SQL find dates that will expire in 6 months from now

Tags: sql, date, calculation

I have a mysql table that contains, among others, the columns `personName`, `board` (a bool that states if person is part of board or not) and `board_date` (a date column that contains the date that the person was elected to the board, if she was).

In my club, the people are elected for 5 year terms. I need to create a query that will return the people whose term will expire in the next 6 months. But I have no clue on how to do that math with those dates.

Can someone please give me a hand? I inherited this system from a previous administrator, and the client wants this. I'm not good with SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use date_add  adding 6 months to now()

```
select * 
from my_table 
where date_add(board_date, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)  
         between now() and  DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: answer  updated  with board_date + 5 years

Comment: Unfortunately, `date_add(board_date, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)` makes it non-[sargeable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/533120). Better to move it to the right side and leave `board_date` "naked".